# Can not access model attributes in render partial on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

js.erb

```
$('#search_div').html('<%=j render :partial=> 'find_book',locals: { book: @results }, :formats => :html  %>')
```

html.erb

```
<% @book=book %>
<%= @book.inspect %>
<% @book.id %>
```

When I do inspect it works find and show me

```
[#<Book id: 55, name: "consequatur laborum quidem excepturi", isbn: 9782943127358, price: 4023, comment: nil, created_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", updated_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", author: nil, sale_type: nil, publisher: nil, sn: nil, category: nil>] [#<Book id: 55, name: "consequatur laborum quidem excepturi", isbn: 9782943127358, price: 4023, comment: nil, created_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", updated_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", author: nil, sale_type: nil, publisher: nil, sn: nil, category: nil>]
```

But when I try to use @book.id

it gives me.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x007faef875b260>):
    1: <% @book=book %>
    2: <%= @book.inspect %>
    3: <% @book.id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `id` because the object `book` is an Array, not a book object. See the `[]` around your inspections.

To read attribute of each book, you need to loop on this local variable.

At first some improvements on the code

1. Use `books` instead of `book` as variable name.
2. Avoid using instance variable when you have local variable available.

Then the code

```
# JS
$('#search_div').html('<%=j render :partial=> 'find_book',
                                   locals: { books: @results } %>'

# partial: _find_book.html.erb
<% books.each do |book| %>
   <%= book.id %>
   <%= book.other_attribute %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see, your @book is an array :

```
[#<Book id: 55, name: "consequatur laborum quidem excepturi", isbn: 9782943127358, price: 4023, comment: nil, created_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", updated_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", author: nil, sale_type: nil, publisher: nil, sn: nil, category: nil>] [#<Book id: 55, name: "consequatur laborum quidem excepturi", isbn: 9782943127358, price: 4023, comment: nil, created_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", updated_at: "2013-09-01 02:59:29", author: nil, sale_type: nil, publisher: nil, sn: nil, category: nil>]
```

Note the "square brackets" ([]) in the start and end. And ass the error shows you cant call id on the array, either do

```
@book.first.id etc
```

or while passing it pass the first result like :

```
$('#search_div').html('<%=j render :partial=> 'find_book',locals: { book: @results.first }, :formats => :html  %>')
```

Or if your plan is to have multiple object then loop through variable @book to show all the details.